# Python Tkinter - sub.Popen with path file

Tags: python, tkinter

i created a simple gui for my project first i show the text which is not edited then i want to show the another text below. Basically i created two  text file and a button . How can i show the output of my script in the second text file with sub.Popen.

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.text = Text()
        self.text.pack()
        self.text1 = Text()
        self.text1.pack()
        menu = Menu(master)
        root.config(menu=menu)
        # file menu
        filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Browse Text File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.file_open)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.file_save)        
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.do_exit)

    def file_open(self):
        """open a file to read"""
        # optional initial directory (default is current directory)
        initial_dir = "C:\Temp"
        # the filetype mask (default is all files)
        mask = \
        [("Text and Python files","*.txt"), 
        ("HTML files","*.htm"), 
        ("All files","*.*")]        
        fin = askopenfile(initialdir=initial_dir, filetypes=mask, mode='r')
        text = fin.read()
        if text != None:
            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(END,text)
        p = sub.Popen('./x4.py',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
        output, errors = p.communicate()
        if text != None:
            self.text1.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text1.insert(END,output)
```

This was the code you can see :

```
p = sub.Popen('./x4.py',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

normally my script takes an sys.argv which is text name. I want to give to my script text file which comes from file_open. Something like that:

```
 p = sub.Popen('./x4.py text(browsed via file open)',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

Comment: if you want a file**name** then just `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`

Comment: cant use on sub.popen because askopenfile() = <open file '/home/arda/Downloads/arda/tmp/tornado/ps/t.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f8c56229db0>

Comment: yes, so ask for a file**NAME** as in `askopenfilename`, that will return the file name as a string, not open the file.

Comment: ok ok thanks i got it know it will exacyle give the path name let me try. Btw thank you

Comment: sorry about the exaggeration, but that is definitely the right direction for what you want.